# Using enum after getting data from a class

Tags: c#, class, enums

I am a beginner to C# and I am currently experimenting with classes and datastructures when I came upon this problem. I want to use the grade char giving char input to get the int output from the enum description of it. Any help would be welcome. Thanks

```
using System;
namespace dataStorageOfFiveStudents
{
     public class StudentData
     {
          public string name;
          public int rollNo;
          public char grade;
          public float gpa;
     }
    public class Program
    {
        enum grading { A=4, B=3, C=2, D=2, F=0};
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Data Entry
            StudentData student1 = new StudentData();
            Console.WriteLine("name?");
            student1.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Roll Number?");
            student1.rollNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Grade");
            student1.grade = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            student1.gpa = (int)grading.student1.grade;
            //Output
            Console.WriteLine("Name =\t" + student1.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Roll No =\t" + student1.rollNo);
            Console.WriteLine("Grade =\t" + student1.grade);
            Console.WriteLine("GPA =\t" + student1.gpa);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) or [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse).

```
grading gpa;
if (Enum.TryParse(student1.grade.ToString(), true, out gpa))
{
    student1.gpa = (float)(int)gpa;
    Console.WriteLine("Name =\t" + student1.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Roll No =\t" + student1.rollNo);
    Console.WriteLine("Grade =\t" + student1.grade);
    Console.WriteLine("GPA =\t" + student1.gpa);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid letter grade");
}
```

Comment: @leppie Thanks for catching that.  I didn't look quite closely enough at `StudentData` at first, but the compilation error should be fixed now.  If only I had Visual Studio handy to test for sure...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enum.Parse`

Assuming:

```
 public class StudenData {
     public string name { get;set; }
     public int rollNo {get;set; }
     public string grade { 
         get { return gpaEnum.ToString(); }
         set { gpaEnum = (grading)Enum.Parse(typeof(grading),value); }
     public gpaEnum { get;set; }
     public int gpa {
         get { return (int)gpaEnum; }
         set { gpaEnum=(grading)value; }
     }
 }
```

Then

```
   //Data Entry   
    StudentData student1 = new StudentData();   
    Console.WriteLine("name?");   
    student1.name = Console.ReadLine();   
    Console.WriteLine("Roll Number?");   
    student1.rollNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   
    Console.WriteLine("Grade");   
    student1.grade = Console.ReadLine();
    //Output   
    Console.WriteLine("Name =\t" + student1.name);   
    Console.WriteLine("Roll No =\t" + student1.rollNo);   
    Console.WriteLine("Grade =\t" + student1.grade);   
    Console.WriteLine("GPA =\t" + student1.gpa); 
    Console.ReadKey();
```

EDIT --- As the data structure appears to be fixed to

```
public class StudenData {
     public string name { get;set; }
     public int rollNo {get;set; }
     public char grade { get;set; }
     public float gpa { get;set; }
 }
```

Then

```
   //Data Entry   
    StudentData student1 = new StudentData();   
    Console.WriteLine("name?");   
    student1.name = Console.ReadLine();   
    Console.WriteLine("Roll Number?");   
    student1.rollNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   
    Console.WriteLine("Grade");   
    grading grade = (grading)Enum.Parse(typeof(grading),Console.ReadLine());
    student1.grade = grade.ToString()[0]; // Grab first char of grade.
    student1.gpa = (float)(int)grade;
    //Output   
    Console.WriteLine("Name =\t" + student1.name);   
    Console.WriteLine("Roll No =\t" + student1.rollNo);   
    Console.WriteLine("Grade =\t" + student1.grade);   
    Console.WriteLine("GPA =\t" + student1.gpa); 
    Console.ReadKey();
```

This code has no error checking you could use Enum.TryParse if you want to add validation checking rather than an exception of a failed parse

Comment: @leppie, are you restricted on student data? If you use my original answer with the changed studentdata it means all the logic is in the class for translating rather than external.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with this code

```
student1.gpa = (int)(Enum.Parse(typeof(grading), student1.grade.ToString().ToUpper()));
```